# Can't use backup with Android Backup Service

Tags: java, android, android-backup-service

I'm trying to integrate the Backup Service with my app. It's all working right up to the moment I make the call to:

```
BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(context);
bm.dataChanged();
```

I see the following in my Logcat:

```
W/BackupManagerService﹕ dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.company.app' uid=10102
```

Here's my implementation of `BackupAgentHelper` https://gist.github.com/cloakedninjas/fe135cb04bf324e26b0c if it helps...

```
public class CordovaBackupAgentHelper extends BackupAgentHelper {
    static final String FILE_NAME = "gameData.json";
    static final String FILES_BACKUP_KEY = "data_file";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        FileBackupHelper helper = new FileBackupHelper(this, FILE_NAME);
        addHelper(FILES_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
                         ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {

        Log.d(Backup.LOG_TAG, "Backup requested: " + oldState.toString() + " | "  + newState.toString());

        synchronized (Backup.sDataLock) {
            Log.d(Backup.LOG_TAG, "Backup requested: " + data.toString());
            super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
                          ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {

        synchronized (Backup.sDataLock) {
            Log.d(Backup.LOG_TAG, "Restore given: " + data.toString());
            super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
        }
    }
}
```

I never see my log entry `Backup requested`. I've checked my Android manifest has the following attribute `android:backupAgent="CordovaBackupAgentHelper"`

Can anyone shed any light on this?

**Update**

I've noticed if I change my Manifest to have `android:backupAgent="FooBar"` I see no errors about undeclared class FooBar, but still see `dataChanged but no participant pkg` when attempting a backup. So my guess is the error is related to not being able to find my backup agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was not putting the attributes onto the correct element :(

I had:

`<manifest android:backupAgent="com.cloakedninjas.cordova.plugins.BackupAgentHelper" ...`

Instead of:

`<application android:backupAgent="com.cloakedninjas.cordova.plugins.BackupAgentHelper"` ...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

In your manifest, I think the declaration of the backup agent should either use the full name or the "dot" short form:

```
android:backupAgent="com.example.project.CordovaBackupAgentHelper"
```

or

```
android:backupAgent=".CordovaBackupAgentHelper"
```

Also, you must have backup enabled in your manifest:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

Having said that, I doubt these changes with make the warning message go away.  I have a backup agent, and am unable to create the warning message you see by changing these declaration to invalid values.

If you are using the Google backup transport, have you registered for the service as described in the [Data Backup Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) and added the key to your manifest?

Have you tried to trigger a backup operation using the `adb bmgr` tool to see if your agent gets called despite the warning message?

Comment: So yeah, tried full name `android:backupAgent="com.cloakedninjas.cordova.plugins.CordovaBackupAgentHelper"` and have added the `android:allowBackup` attribute. Key is in the manifest as per the <meta> specified and have triggered `adb shell bmgr run` several times. But thanks :)

Comment: Just wondering, does the app need to be published to work? It's not been uploaded to Google Play yet

Comment: Also also, if you change your API key to something incorrect, does that generate any warnings?

Comment: @cloakedninjas My app is not published and I have successfully backed-up and restored using the Google transport.  When you do `bmgr run`, is your agent invoked?

Comment: Nope, but it does successfully backup `com.android.providers.settings` + `android` + `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`

Comment: @cloakedninjas I changed my backup key to an invalid value and didn't see the warning message.